# How to add delay to touch events just like the UIScrollView does

Tags: iphone, uitouch

How to add delay to touch events just like the UIScrollView does?

I want to check move events before passing the touch events to subviews?

The UIScrollView could do this, scrolling the subviews before click on them.

But I don't want to scroll the content.  I want to filter the events and pass move events to certain subview.